# Impulse and change in momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, definition

What exactly is [Impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics))? Is impulse only defined for "significant large force acting for a small interval of time" or can it have more "generalized" meaning?

My perspective about impulse is that
" It's a change (big OR small) in the momentum of a body in a short period of time due to a resultant force.." is this correct or does this definition need some changes ?
Also,
If impulse,J = ∆P (change in momentum) then this would violate the above stated definition. ( I am not sure whether J = ∆P is true for all physical scenarios )

But then again,
Suppose I punch a wall (don't mind me:) now obviously I have applied a force F on the wall for a small time "dt"..
So according to the definition of impulse in my book and wikipedia, Impulse on this wall would be
J = Fdt right ?
But it should also be equal to ∆P ?
And here ∆P is clearly zero as the wall has not acquired any velocity in the time "dt"

So I would need a clear explanation on what impulse is and how exactly is it different from change in momentum for a physical scenario (and whether J = ∆P is always true or not)

Comment: Have you tried reading [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics))...? The general definition and its derivation is presented almost immediately there. *Note: General in the sense of Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/impulse.html

Comment: Another victim of the incorrect translation. I believe, you're from an American university. Or from a country that follows the English scientific tradition. Just remember: momentum IS impulse. Somebody gave a wrong translation a century ago, and now people think that impulse and momentum are two different things and, what's the most ridiculous, try to give a theoretical explanation to that. See discussion in the comments under this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/657842/238538. That's not the only inappropriate thing going on in America. Thus, people here use tan^(-1) for arctan.

Answer (score 1):

The impulse of a force $\mathbf F(t)$ between times $t_1$ and $t_2$ is defined by
$$\mathbf J=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbf F\ dt$$
The time interval, ($t_2-t_1$), need not be short, though 'impulse' is especially useful for a large force, $\mathbf F$, acting for a short time interval, because we can then neglect much smaller forces acting on the same body at the same time. [For example if I kick a ball lying on the ground, we can reasonably neglect the frictional force acting on the ball during the short time my foot is in contact with the ball.] So the body's change in momentum is
$$\Delta \mathbf p = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathbf p}{dt} dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\mathbf F\ dt = \mathbf J$$
In the case you mention of punching the wall it is *not* permissible to neglect all other forces on the wall except the punch. This is because the wall is (or should be) firmly attached to the ground, so when you punch it a force acts on it from the ground, in the opposite direction to the force of your punch.

You can still use the notion of impulse to determine a body's change in momentum if more than one significant force acts on a body simultaneously. We then have
$$\Delta{\mathbf p}=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{d\mathbf p}{dt} dt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sum \mathbf F\ dt=\sum\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \mathbf F dt=\sum \mathbf J,$$
in which $\sum \mathbf F$ is the vector sum of the forces acting on the body at time $t$, and $\sum \mathbf J$ is the vector sum of the impulses over the given time interval of all the forces acting on the body.

Comment: Oh ok, so whether we use Impulse or change in momentum depends on simply the time for the change and whether we can ignore "non- significant forces" (which bring negligible change in the momentum of the body) so If momentum of a body changes in a longer time such that only a single force was acting on it, then this change will not be specially referred as "an impulse" (as the time period for the change was large) correct? Or is it that we still may call it an impulse since obviously it's magnitude will be equal to the change in momentum?

Comment: "whether we use Impulse or change in momentum depends on simply the time for the change and whether we can ignore "non- significant forces" I'm afraid that I can't agree with this. My first equation defines the impulse of a force over any given time interval. The last equation relates a body's change in momentum to the vector sum of the impulses of the forces acting on it and is true for any given time interval. It is my middle equation, relating change in momentum to the impulse of a *single* force that is sometimes used as an approximation, when smaller forces may be neglected.

Comment: A typical case when smaller forces may be neglected is when one very large force acts for a short time. [See my football example.] That does **not** imply that impulse is only defined for large forces and short time intervals. As I've tried to explain, a body's change in momentum over a given time interval is always equal to the vector sum of the impulses of the forces acting on the body over that interval.